# XCode 8: Can't find AFNetworking header files and Swift pods errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Today I've upgraded my XCode to 8 version, but After this I got a lot of errors. Ex:

> The targets “Charts” and “CircleProgressView” contain source code developed with an earlier version of Swift.
>
> Choose “Convert” to update the source code in these targets to the
>   latest SDKs. You will be given the choice to use Swift 2.3 syntax or
>   update to Swift 3.
>
> This action can be performed later using “Convert to Current Swift
>   Syntax” in the Edit menu.

And AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h file not found. The steps I made:

1. Added `post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
     config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
   end
   end
   end` to my Podfile
2. Updated my `cocoapods gem` to a latest version.

After the 1st step my error about swift module has left. But I still can't find header of my `AFNetworking`. Help me out please

Comment: same here. Let me know if you find an answer.

Comment: What does your Podfile looks like? Maybe you should not use these post_install lines for a framework written in Objective-C.

Comment: @Tulleb http://pastebin.com/8yHtFcLR

Comment: @Tulleb almost same as Artem's https://www.dropbox.com/s/qs63e4avlvqzxwi/Podfile?dl=0

Comment: @Tulleb additional here is my build settings https://www.dropbox.com/s/44cb31dh2gmws3u/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-28%20at%204.01.51%20PM.png?dl=0 I am not getting Legacy Swift option.

Comment: Sorry I don't have ideas for your problem since you already had it before adding the post_install lines, right? So it's not caused by that I guess. Maybe you should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377450/cocoapods-1-0-header-files-not-found.

Comment: @Tulleb I've already tried this post

Comment: @ArtemZ link Tulleb mentioned, works for me.